# How can I prevent dropdown.min.js from loading on the front end of my website?

Tags: joomla-4.x, javascript, bootstrap, dropdown

dropdown.min.js is conflicting with the way I have my menu set up in my Joomla 4 website, but I can't disable it entirely because the back end of the website needs it. How can I keep it enabled for the back end but disable it for the front end?

Comment: I've actually seen that thread, tried it, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unset` command to disable a script in the front-end.

I suppose that you might try the following method that worked in Joomla 3. Add something like the following to your front-end template:

```
unset($this->_styleSheets[$this->baseurl .'/path/to/the/css/file.css']);
```

See: https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=977796

Comment: I'd also recommend creating a child template first, rather than editing the main `index.php`